# Speed up Sinatra page load with Ajax?

Tags: ruby, ajax, load, sinatra, erb

I am using the Sinatra to develop a web application but I am running into long page load time issue.

The application goes through and display a lot of data so I am sure this is the cause but I was wondering if there was a way to have the main erb layout of the page load first and then after that load, the data loads on top of it.

My first thought was AJAX but I am not sure how I would implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it may help. The old mantra of "separate that which changes from that which does not" is applicable in any part of programming.

Here's route that returns some data:

```
require 'json'
get "/time-now/?" do
  content_type :json
  {time: Time.now.to_s}.to_json
end
```

and here's some javascript ([jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) to call it:

```
$.ajax({
  accepts: "application/json",
  type: "GET",
  url: "/time-now",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(res, status, xhr) {
    return [$("#time").html(res)];
  },
  error: function(res, status, xhr) {
    return [$("#time").addClass("error")];
  },
  complete: function(res, status, xhr) {
    return [$("#button1").show()];
  }
});
```

(that bit of jQuery may be a little bit wrong, just warning you, it's a copy 'n paste job hacked to fit this example)

Perhaps you could stop serving user pages from Sinatra routes and use static (i.e. prebuilt) pages with javascript in them that make AJAX calls to Sinatra routes. Or a mixture of the two types. Then you've got the start of a web service data API. There are lots of javascript frameworks to help with this, (e.g. Ember, Backbone, Angular and many more) and plenty of API builders alongside Sinatra, like [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) and [Weasel Diesel](https://github.com/mattetti/Weasel-Diesel).